# Twig installation and path direction

Tags: php, twig, template-engine

I am facing the problem while installing my project. The details about it are as follows:

1. my project works on the PHP, mySql, and m working on windows xp SP2
2. it also needed to install imagick and doctrine. I have installed these with XAMPP; now it is showing me error about the twig, which is:

> Twig needs to be installed and in the PHP include_path.
>   "Twig_Autoloader was not found"

3. I have included path in `php.ini` file as `"C:\Program Files\xampp\php\PEAR\DoctrineORM-2.2.0"`
4. downloaded and extract Twig 1.8.2 into `"C:\Program Files\xampp\php\PEAR\DoctrineORM-2.2.0\Doctrine\Symfony\Component"` but still it's not working.

Please get me the solution over it.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, PHP already looks in the PEAR directory as an include when you have installed the XAMPP application on a windows machine. I installed TWIG folowing the PEAR installation instructions from the TWIG site.
Just include the autoloader ..

```
require_once 'Twig/Autoloader.php';
Twig_Autoloader::register();
```

And follow the instruction from the [TWIG site](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/intro.html)